# YII: Access Rules doesn't work with Chrome but Work With Firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, yii

I use latest version of YII v1.1.14:
I create controller with the following code:

```
class MyController extends CController
{

    public $layout='//layouts/column1';


    public $menu=array();

    public $breadcrumbs=array();
    public $resourceUrl = '';
    public $pageTitle = '' ;
    public $pageSubTitle = '';
    public $baseUrl = '' ;
    public $themeUrl ='';
    public $additionalJS = '' ;
    public $currentMenu = '' ; // for menu highlighting (use small case)


    public function init(){
        $this->themeUrl = YII::app()->theme->baseUrl;
        $this->resourceUrl = YII::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/resources/';
        $this->pageTitle = strtoupper(Yii::app()->controller->id) ;
        $this->baseUrl = YII::app()->baseUrl;
        $this->currentMenu = 'home';
    }

    public function isCurrentMenu($topic){
        if($this->currentMenu == $topic)
            return 'current-menu-item';
    }
}


class DashboardController extends MyController
{
    public $active = 'dashboard';
    public $pageTitle = 'Dashboard';
    public $pageSubTitle = 'manage your inventory and all stuff';
    public $layout = '//layouts/dashboard';

    public function filters()
    {
        return array( 'accessControl' ); // perform access control for CRUD operations
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','createStuff'),
                'roles'=>array('user'),
                //'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->roles== "admin"',
                //'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('delete'),
                'roles'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('indxex'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function actionCreateStuff()
    {
        $this->render('createStuff');
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        //echo Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('user');exit;
        $this->render('index',array());
    }

....

}
```

in main.php

```
'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'class'=>'WebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'loginUrl'=>array('site/login'),
            'returnUrl'=>array('dashboard/index'),
        ),
```

When I tried to access that page with Google Chrome, the access rule wont work, it just allow alll access to that page ... but with Mozilla Firefox, it did the right thing by fowarding to Login Page first.

How to debug this bug on chrome ?

ERROR Page: (for better view https://www.dropbox.com/s/ceg1o06n8bj4vk5/PHP%20notice.pdf)

> ```
> PHP notice
>
> Trying to get property of non-object
>
> D:\xampp\htdocs\buntelangame\themes\initializr\views\layouts\dashboard.php(75)
>
> 63 <a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
> 64 </a>
> 65 <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
> 66 <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
> 67 <div class="top-menu">
> 68 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
> 69 
> 70 <!-- BEGIN USER LOGIN DROPDOWN -->
> 71 <li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
> 72     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
> 73         <img alt="" class="img-circle" src="<?php echo $this->themeUrl; ?>/assets/admin/layout/img/avatar3_small.jpg"/>
> 74                     <span class="username">
> 75                     <?php echo Yii::app()->session['user']->nama_lengkap;?> </span>
> 76         <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
> 77     </a>
> 78     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
> 79         <li>
> 80             <a href="extra_profile.html">
> 81                 <i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile </a>
> 82         </li>
> 83         <li>
> 84             <a href="inbox.html">
> 85                 <i class="icon-envelope-open"></i> My Inbox <span class="badge badge-danger">
> 86                             3 </span>
> 87             </a>
> Stack Trace
> #0    
> +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CBaseController.php(126): require("D:\xampp\htdocs\buntelangame\themes\initializr\views\layouts\das...")
> #1    
> +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CBaseController.php(95): CBaseController->renderInternal("D:\xampp\htdocs\buntelangame\themes\initializr\views//layouts/da...",
> ```
>
> array("content" => "
>
> ## dashboard/index
>
> This page will be
>   contains, st..."), true)
>       #2
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CController.php(784): CBaseController->renderFile("D:\xampp\htdocs\buntelangame\themes\initializr\views//layouts/da...",
>   array("content" => "
>
> ## dashboard/index
>
> This page will be
>   contains, st..."), true)
>       #3
>       –  D:\xampp\htdocs\buntelangame\protected\controllers\DashboardController.php(46):
>   CController->render("index", array())
>       41     }
>       42 
>       43     public function actionIndex()
>       44     {
>       45         //echo Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('user');exit;
>       46         $this->render('index',array());
>       47     }
>       48 
>       49     public function actionListStuff()
>       50     {
>       51         $this->render('listStuff');
>       #4
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): DashboardController->actionIndex()
>       #5
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("/dashboard/index" => ""))
>       #6
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(133): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
>       #7
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(40): CFilterChain->run()
>       #8
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CController.php(1145): CFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
>       #9
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(58): CController->filterAccessControl(CFilterChain)
>       #10
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(130): CInlineFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
>       #11
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()
>       #12
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction,
>   array("accessControl"))
>       #13
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run("index")
>       #14
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController("dashboard/index")
>       #15
>       +  D:\yii\bin\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
>       #16
>       –  D:\xampp\htdocs\buntelangame\index.php(13): CApplication->run()
>       08 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
>       09 // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
>       10 defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
>       11 
>       12 require_once($yii);
>       13 Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
>       2014-07-11 18:43:39 Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 Yii Framework/1.1.14

EDIT:
it work in icognito mode.
my google chrome version :Version 35.0.1916.153 m

Comment: Real quick: latest version is 1.1.15.  This doesn't affect your issue but does a major security fix.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: trying to upgrade to 1.115 (latest version) ... still doesnt work on chrome.

Comment: clearing the cache wont help too... still producing the same problem.

Comment: The error: `Trying to get property of non-object` is the issue and typically means that somewhere you are referencing `$someArray->asAnObject`.  Also, your code should be not working in both browsers.  I would try to clear in both browsers or even try incognito mode.  Hope that points you in the right direction

Comment: weird.. in icognito mode it works well just like in firefox.

The error: Trying to get property of non-object ==> is due to code that accessing the session. Session of user will be created after user logged in